# problems with grunt tasks

Tags: gruntjs

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "pink",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Личный проект «Пинк» от HTML Academy",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@htmlacademy/editorconfig-cli": "0.1.x",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-browser-sync": "2.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-css-mqpacker": "^3.0.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "0.8.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^4.0.0",
    "grunt-svgstore": "^1.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.2",
    "postcss-csso": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "editorconfig-cli",
    "build": "grunt less && grunt postcss",
    "start": "npm run build && grunt serve"
  },
  "editorconfig-cli": [
    "*.html",
    "*.json",
    "*.js",
    "js/**/*.js",
    "img/**/*.svg",
    "less/**/*.less"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.7"
  }
}
```

Gruntfile.js is:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require("load-grunt-tasks")(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      style: {
        files: {
          "css/style.css": "less/style.less"
        }
      }
    },

    postcss: {
      style: {
        options: {
          processors: [
            require("autoprefixer")({browsers: [
              "last 1 versions",
              "last 2 Chrome versions",
              "last 2 Firefox versions",
              "last 2 Opera versions",
              "last 2 Edge versions",
            ]}),
          ]
        },
        src: "css/*.css"
      }
    },

    browserSync: {
      server: {
        bsFiles: {
          src: [
            "*.html",
            "css/*.css"
          ]
        },
        options: {
          server: ".",
          watchTask: true,
          notify: false,
          open: true,
          cors: true,
          ui: false
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      style: {
        files: ["less/**/*.less"],
        tasks: ["less", "postcss"]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("serve", ["browserSync", "watch"]);
};
```

All Grunt tasks are working well.

I added a new grunt plugin, for example, imagemin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-imagemin).

My updated Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```js
"use strict";

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require("load-grunt-tasks")(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      style: {
        files: {
          "css/style.css": "less/style.less"
        }
      }
    },

    postcss: {
      style: {
        options: {
          processors: [
            require("autoprefixer")({browsers: [
              "last 1 versions",
              "last 2 Chrome versions",
              "last 2 Firefox versions",
              "last 2 Opera versions",
              "last 2 Edge versions",
            ]}),
          ]
        },
        src: "css/*.css"
      }
    },

    // Configuration for imagemin-task
    imagemin: {
      dynamic: {
        options: {
          optimizationLevel: 3
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: "src/",
          src: ["images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}"],
          dest: "img/"
        }]
      }
    }

    browserSync: {
      server: {
        bsFiles: {
          src: [
            "*.html",
            "css/*.css"
          ]
        },
        options: {
          server: ".",
          watchTask: true,
          notify: false,
          open: true,
          cors: true,
          ui: false
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      style: {
        files: ["less/**/*.less"],
        tasks: ["less", "postcss"]
      }
    }
  });

  // Here is registerTask
  grunt.registerTask("default", ["imagemin"]);
  grunt.registerTask("serve", ["browserSync", "watch"]);
};
```

After this addition, no tasks work anymore.

Terminal shows me the following error:

> Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>
> > > SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Warning: Task "less" not found. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.
>
> bash: --force: command not found

The same error appears for all tasks (for example, `grunt less`, which was working correctly before the last addition).

What's wrong? Please help me.

After addition the comma's and new plugins initConfig is following:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      style: {
        files: {
          "css/style.css": "less/style.less"
        }
      }
    },

    postcss: {
      style: {
        options: {
          processors: [
            require("autoprefixer")({browsers: [
              "last 1 versions",
              "last 2 Chrome versions",
              "last 2 Firefox versions",
              "last 2 Opera versions",
              "last 2 Edge versions",
            ]}),
          ]
        },
        src: "css/*.css"
      }
    },

    csso: {
      style: {
        options: {
          report: "gzip"
        },
        files: {
          "css/style.min.css": "css/style.css"
        }
      }
    },

    imagemin: {
      images: {
        options: {
          optimizationLevel: 3
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: "src/",
          src: ["images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}"],
          dest: "img/"
        }]
      }
    },

    svgstore: {
      options: {
        svg: {
          style: "display: none"
        }
      }
      symbols: {
        files: {
          "images/symbols.svg": "images/icons/*.svg"
        }
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      symbols: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ["images/icons/*.svg"]
        }]
      }
    },

    browserSync: {
      server: {
        bsFiles: {
          src: [
            "*.html",
            "css/*.css"
          ]
        },
        options: {
          server: ".",
          watchTask: true,
          notify: false,
          open: true,
          cors: true,
          ui: false
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      style: {
        files: ["less/**/*.less"],
        tasks: ["less", "postcss"]
      }
    }
  });
```

But I have the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the (newly added) `imagemin` block:

```js
imagemin: {
    // ...
} // <- right here

browserSync: {
    // ...
```

Comment: Eliran, thank u! That's helped. But I tried to add new plugins, and I have the same mistake again. Could u help me please? (I refreshed the question and added new initConfig)

Comment: @spp, if that solved your issue, please tick the answer as accepted, or upvote it. regardless, if you still have issues it's best not to update your old question, but to post a new one with only the relevant data (see [the help docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write a kick-ass question).

Comment: by the way, you're issue is still the same, you are missing a comma inside the `svgstore` block. run the json that goes into the config object through a [JSON validator](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) to avoid such problems in the future.

Comment: sure, no problem :)